# How to disable last 3 days and future DateTimePicker android

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm try to use DateTimePicker first time and I am confuse to disable by last 3 days and future day. Hmmm maybe I has been research in http://tips.androidgig.com/disable-future-dates-from-datepickerdialog/
but I cannot implement in my function.

This is my function for show DateTimePicker when I click TextView

```
private void setDatePicker() {
calDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calDate2 = Calendar.getInstance();
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSet1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int date) {
    calDate1.set(year, month, date);
    displayDate(tvDate1, calDate1);
  }
};
tvDate1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    new DatePickerDialog(TicketStatusActivity.this, dateSet1, calDate1.get(Calendar.YEAR), calDate1.get(Calendar.MONTH), calDate1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
  }
});
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSet2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int date) {
    calDate2.set(year, month, date);
    displayDate(tvDate2, calDate2);
  }
};
tvDate2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    new DatePickerDialog(TicketStatusActivity.this, dateSet2, calDate2.get(Calendar.YEAR), calDate2.get(Calendar.MONTH), calDate2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
  }
});
displayDate(tvDate1, calDate1);
displayDate(tvDate2, calDate2);}
```

Sorry if this question not important and my grammar is bad
고맙습니다

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set MaxDate in datepicker.

Try with this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);
        DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: It is worked to my, but why disable until day - 4 and in day - 4 cannot select.
for example now = 2018-08-10
days - 3 = 2018-08-08
It is should be 8,9,10 can click and not disabled, but not like that, 7,8,9,10 is not disabled. I am test for click 7 is cannot but not disabled in interface ?